# SQL Server 2014 "for xml path" into View

Tags: sql-server

I have a query that works well on its own, putting multiple values into a single column:

```
select substring(
(
    select '/'+ Convert(nvarchar,OE) AS 'data()' 
    from wpb1.dbo.OE_table
    where QDBID = 605441478 
    for xml path('')
)
,2, 255) as list1
```

And I have this View that I want to put it into, which works fine on its own:

```
SELECT 
   DISTINCT wpb1.dbo.Quotes.[Quote Num], MIN(wpb1.dbo.OE_table.OE) AS [Min OE], 
   COUNT(wpb1.dbo.OE_table.OE) AS [Count OE]
FROM wpb1.dbo.Quotes 
LEFT OUTER JOIN wpb1.dbo.OE_table 
ON wpb1.dbo.Quotes.QuoteDBID = wpb1.dbo.OE_table.QDBID
GROUP BY wpb1.dbo.Quotes.[Quote Num]
```

But when I try it causes an error saying:

> Error in WHERE clause near '('. Error in GROUP BY clause. Unable to
>   parse query text.

This is what I am trying:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT wpb1.dbo.Quotes.[Quote Num], MIN(wpb1.dbo.OE_table.OE) AS [Min OE], 
    COUNT(wpb1.dbo.OE_table.OE) AS [Count OE],
    (
        select substring(
        (
            select '/'+ Convert(nvarchar,OE) AS 'data()' 
            from wpb1.dbo.OE_table  
            where QDBID = 605441478 
            for xml path('')
        ),2, 255)
    ) as list1
FROM wpb1.dbo.Quotes LEFT OUTER JOIN wpb1.dbo.OE_table 
ON wpb1.dbo.Quotes.QuoteDBID = wpb1.dbo.OE_table.QDBID
GROUP BY wpb1.dbo.Quotes.[Quote Num]
```

What am I doing wrong?
Using SQL Server 2014.

Comment: What values are in `OE` column?

Comment: Try specifying the length for your conversion of OE.  Convert(nvarchar(10),OE) or however long you need it to be.

Comment: OE is a 6 digit integer.

Comment: I tried Convert(nvarchar(10),OE) but same message.
It wont even parse the query because apparently its the wrong syntax. 
It asks me to ignore or undo my edit.

Comment: So I have this working as a query but it wont accept it in a View, why is that? - -         
SELECT OE1.QDBID,
(select substring((select '/'+ Convert(nvarchar(10),OE2.OE)  AS 'data()' from wpb1.dbo.OE_table as OE2  where OE1.QDBID = OE2.QDBID for xml path('')),2, 512)) as list1 
FROM OE_table as OE1

Comment: I guess you just cant do that in a View.